# how to open ubuntu from iphone

Tags: ssh, ftp, iphone, ios

i want to open my ubuntu ssh and show files from my ios device how ?
i tried a lot of apps Like Ftp Manager and openssh and website like net2ftp and everything goes wrong

Comment: Is your iOS device Jailbroken if yes? then download "Newterm 2" (Terminal for iphone) from Cydia.
check the ssh installed on iphone, if not download (ssh and vsftpd packages)from cydia.
before connecting to your iphone you should reset root password or use defauld password "alpine".
connect your iPhone in same wifi network and do the ssh from iPhone "Newterm 2"
ssh root@your ubuntu machine ip.

Comment: Just a note, jailbreaking a device can come with consequences, so don't rush to do that if you aren't familiar with what the downsides to doing this are.

Answer (score 0):

@rikz
Is your iOS device Jailbroken if yes? then download "Newterm 2" (Terminal for iphone) from Cydia.

check the ssh installed on iphone, if not download (ssh and vsftpd packages)from cydia.

before connecting to your iphone you should reset root password or use defauld password "alpine".

connect your iPhone in same wifi network and do the ssh from iPhone "Newterm 2"
ssh root@your ubuntu machine ip.

Answer (score 0):

On apple iPad I use the app termius to connect via ssh using known username and password.

From there I run x11vnc on the ubuntu server using the command:

sudo x11vnc -display :0 -auth guess

Lastly I connect to its desktop using vncviewer.

Hope that helps.